understanding the property of partition of unity
Let $Ω⊂R^n$ be open  , $Ω=∪Ω_i$ , i∈I  , $Ω_i$ open ⇒∃ {$φ_i$:i∈I}  partition of unity such that

"support" ($φ_i$ )⊂$Ω_i$ ∀ i∈I .
{"support" ($φ_i$) ∶i∈I}  is locally finite .
0≤$φ_i$ (x)≤ 1 and $φ_i$∈$C^∞$ (Ω).
$∑_{i∈I}$$φ_i$ (x)=1

Consider $I$ countable and |Ω|<∞  and |$Ω_i$|<∞ ⇒ support ($φ_i$) is closed ( by deffinition) and bounded ( by 1 ) so is compact .
Q1 : Define the sequence $ψ_n$=$∑_{i<n}$$φ_i$ ⇒ $ψ_n$ converges point wise to 1 . By (1) and (3) ⇒$φ_i$∈$C_0^∞$(Ω) ⇒$ψ_n$∈$C_0^∞$(Ω) . So I have found a sequence $ψ_n$∈$C_0^∞$(Ω) such that $ψ_n$→1 point wise , is this ok ?
Q2 : To be less strict with my formulation my problem arrases from property 1 and 4. Prop. 1 forces the function to vanish outside a compact, but 4 forces it to add up to 1 on an open set containing the aforementioned compacts. The only way I see this happening is if Ω=∪support($φ_i$) is this the way we should understand it ?

your reasoning in Q1 and Q2 is fine.

Please take a closer look at our guildelines for using mathjax to typeset the mathematics in your post. For Greek letters do not use unicode characters like Ω, instead use mathjax commands like \Omega. And for math symbols do not use unicode characters like ∈, instead look up the mathjax command like \in.

I don't see why the assumptions imply that the supports of $\varphi_i$ are bounded. $\Omega_0 = \Omega = \mathbf{R}^n$, $\varphi_0 \equiv 1$, $\varphi_i \equiv 0 $ for $i \ne 0$ seems valid

Yes, (1) and (2) are both possible, and that's what happens. Think of $(0,1) = \bigcup_{n\ge 3}[1/n,1-1/n]$ as a union of compact sets. Or even $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{n\ge 1}[-n,n]$.
The proofs of the construction of partition of unity usually rely in some way on this "exhaustion by compact sets." We write an open set as a countable union of compact sets in some way.
